# I am getting blank black page while trying to use flick video player package

Tags: flutter, dart, video, video-streaming

i got a blank page while trying to use flick video playe package, i have enabled internet permission in manifest file still got a black blank page on loading the video from url, i tried loading video from asset as well same error, i added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" as well same error

```
import 'package:fit/utils/extension.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flick_video_player/flick_video_player.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class Warm_Up extends StatefulWidget {
  const Warm_Up({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Warm_Up> createState() => _Warm_UpState();
}

class _Warm_UpState extends State<Warm_Up> {
  late FlickManager flickManager;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flickManager = FlickManager(
      videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.network(
          "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flickManager.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                  onTap: () => context.back(),
                  child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined)),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 170,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                child: AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1280 / 720,
                  child: FlickVideoPlayer(flickManager: flickManager),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Problem is with your link. Try this : videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.network(
          "https://github.com/GeekyAnts/flick-video-player-demo-videos/blob/master/example/rio_from_above_compressed.mp4?raw=true"),

Comment: W/com.example.fi(10313): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioTrack;->getLatency()I (greylist, reflection, allowed) i still get this error after changing link